# Select suite of tests for coverage with pytest

Tags: python, pytest, code-coverage, coverage.py

I'm running a set of tests with `pytest` and want also to measure its coverage with the `coverage` package.

I have some decorators in my code, dividing the tests in several suites using something like:

```
@pytest.mark.firstgroup
def test_myfirsttest():
    assert True is True

@pytest.mark.secondgroup
def test_mysecondtest():
    assert False is False
```

I need to find something like:

`coverage run --suite=firstgroup -m pytest`

So that in this case only the first test, since it's in the correct suite, will be used to test coverage.

The suites work correctly when I use directly `pytest` but I don't know how to use them in `coverage`

Is there any way to configure `coverage` to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass whatever arguments you want to pytest.  If this line works:

```
pytest --something --also=another 1 2 foo bar
```

then you can run it under coverage like this:

```
coverage run -m pytest --something --also=another 1 2 foo bar
```